# DataTable AjaxSource

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I'm going straight to the point here.
what I am trying to accomplish is to populate the table using ajax.

this gives me `jquery.dataTables.min.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error.

here's my code:

**my php code:**

```
public function pending_data(){

    $result = $this->ticketing_m->get_pending_tickets();
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var datatable = $("#datatable");

datatable.DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": datatable.data('url')
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <table id="datatable"  class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" data-url="<?php echo site_url(array("dashboard","pending_data")); ?>">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket Number</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**QUERY RESULT**
[image]

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz console.log error `jquery.dataTables.min.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Is that jQuery code executing after the page is loaded?

Comment: Why are you using outdated properties?  What version of datatables?  What is the output of `get_pending_tickets()`?  The problem here is probably that you don't have `data` defined in the response but it's impossible to say for sure since you have not included that in your question.

Comment: @SougataBose yes sir... I will post the result of the query here.. I am really new to this.. so please bear with me

Comment: also, you should not be using serverside processing unless you are doing server side processing - which you clearly are not based on your code.

Comment: @billynoah I have posted the query result sir..

Comment: Thanks @SamTengWong - I retracted my close vote and posted some helpful info below in an answer.  Hopefully it gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should probably set `bServerSide` to `false`.  If it is `true` you need to actually read the request parameters, do server side processing and structure your return data as outlined in the [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) documentation.  Since you are doing none of those things here I'm assuming you simply want to use Ajax sourced data and let the DataTables javascript handle the table processing

Next, structure your json with the table data inside `data` as shown [here](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location) in example #2.  Your json should look something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "date_created": "2017-06-13 13:57:24",
            "full_name": "John Doe",
            "subject": "Test",
            "ticket_number": "Ticket 1234"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

To accomplish this you might do something as simple as this in the response from `pending_data()`:

```
echo json_encode(array('data' => $result));
```

Also, the way you have your DataTables properties set up here looks like you are either using a very old version or an outdated syntax.  I'd suggest installing the latest version and using up to date code.  You can get all the downloads and examples you might need at: https://datatables.net

Answer (score 1):

I think your ajax source has 4 columns.
But you have 5 columns in < thead >.
Pls remove one  tag in < thead >.

```
<table id="datatable"  class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" data-url="<?php echo site_url(array("dashboard","pending_data")); ?>">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket Number</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry my bad.. I have already updated my file.. I forgot to update my question here.. there should be 4 column..

Answer (score 0):

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/",
"aoColumns" : [
{ "mData": "Ticket Numbe" },
{ "mData": "Subject" },
{ "mData": "From" },
{ "mData": "Date Created" }
]
});
```

I don't get the exact problem.This may help..

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that also use data type https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/jsonp.html

```
 "processing": true,
 "serverSide": true, 
 "ajax": {
            "url": "scripts/jsonp.php",
            "dataType": "jsonp"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like:

```
var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbEfqLwFaq?indent=2';

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
      type: 'POST',
      'url': url,
      'data': function (d) {
        console.log(d.order);
        return JSON.stringify( d );
      }
    }

  });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/ntcwust8/)